# Scroll jcarouselLite on W

Tags: jcarousel, jcarousellite

In a WordPress theme that I have bought there is a slider that I need some help with.  Currently it does not scroll, it simply has a left and right arrow to proceed two slides forwards or backwards.  The main thing I need is for the slider to automatically scroll.

After asking for help in the theme's support forum, the theme developer told me I would need to edit the following lines in the theme's .js file.  Here are the lines I was told I would need to edit.

```
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#latest-wrapper .latest").jCarouselLite({       
            btnNext: ".latest-next",        
            btnPrev: ".latest-prev",
            easing: "easeInOutExpo",
            speed: 700,
            visible: 5,
            scroll: 2       
        }); 
    });
```

I'm quite new to this, but I've found my learning curve for this is incredibly fast.  If anyone has any suggestions, that would really be appreciated.

**P.S.** The slider is the second, and larger of the two, at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#latest-wrapper .latest").jCarouselLite({       
            btnNext: ".latest-next",        
            btnPrev: ".latest-prev",
            easing: "easeInOutExpo",
            auto: 3000,
            speed: 700,
            visible: 5,
            scroll: 2       
        }); 
    });

 * @option auto : number - default is null, meaning autoscroll is disabled by default
 * @example
 * $(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
 *      auto: 800,
 *      speed: 500
 * });
 * @desc You can make your carousel auto-navigate itself by specfying a millisecond value in this option.
 * The value you specify is the amount of time between 2 slides. The default is null, and that disables auto scrolling.
 * Specify this value and magically your carousel will start auto scrolling.
 *
```